# Как применять координатные преобразования к региону в GDI+?

Tags: c++, windows, delphi, gdi+

В [этой](https://rsdn.org/article/gdi/gdiplus1.xml) статье приведена следующая информация:

> регионы теперь не привязаны к координатам устройства и подчиняются координатным преобразованиям.

Никак не получается это осуществить. Может кто использовал этот функционал? 
У меня только как в первой GDI получается крутить холст целиком.
Как применять координатные преобразования именно к региону?

Answer (score 0):

> Регионы: в отличие от GDI, регионы теперь не привязаны к координатам
>   устройства и подчиняются координатным преобразованиям

Это странная сентенция. В GDI регионы работают в логических координатах (page coordinate system, logical pixels), а не в device координатах. И они подвергаются мировым преобразованиям. Пример:

```
var
  hr: HRGN;
  xf: XFOrm;
begin
  xf.eM11 := 0.87;
  xf.eM12 := -0.5;
  xf.eM21 := 0.5;
  xf.eM22 := 0.87;
  xf.eDx := -50;
  xf.eDy := 50;
  SetGraphicsMode(Canvas.Handle, GM_ADVANCED);
  SetWorldTransform(Canvas.Handle, xf);
  hr := CreateRectRgn(120, 120, 220, 220);
  Canvas.Brush.Color := clGreen;
  FillRgn(Canvas.Handle, hr, Canvas.Brush.Handle);
```

Как бы то ни было, фраза `подчиняются координатным преобразованиям` не означает, что матрица преобразования применяется только  к выбранному региону.

Возможно, желаемого эффекта можно достичь, используя регион отсечения.

Comment: "не означает, что матрица преобразования применяется только к выбранному региону."  
Жалко, я почему-то понял это именно так...  Мне хотелось бы именно матрицу преобразования применять к конкретному региону. Про регион отсечения надо пойти почитать, никогда не слышал. Если есть возможность привести примерчик, буду благодарен

Comment: SetClipRgn(...)

Comment: А нельзя нарисовать регион на отдельном холсте со своими преобразованиями, а потом скопировать его в нужное место?

Comment: @kot-da-vinci Вероятно, можно. Однако для копирования региона (именно его без окружения) нужно задать его как регион отсечения, так что проще сразу на нужном холсте всё делать (если других целей не преследуется)

Comment: @MBo, спасибо за наводку, поколдую на досуге, отпишусь

Comment: @MBo, я имел ввиду скопировать весь отдельный холст целиком.

Comment: @kot-da-vinci Тогда я не понимаю - в чём отличие от рисования на нужном холсте сразу?

Comment: @MBo, "не означает, что матрица преобразования применяется только к выбранному региону." Как оказалось - означает! Нашёл я как это делается наконец. Там имеется метод GdipTransformRegion(Region: GpRegion; Matrix: GpMatrix) как раз для этих целей, прекрасно работает.

Comment: @MBo, в том, что на отдельном холсте можно применять отдельные матрицы преобразования.

Comment: @kot-da-vinci, и для отдельного региона и для отдельного пути в плюсе имплементировано

Comment: @Isaev Тогда стоит сделать свой ответ и показать простой пример, как это выглядит.

Answer (score 0):

Простенький примерчик на примере геометрических путей (Path), работа с регионами абсолютно аналогична:

```
Const
  PolyPoints: Array[0..8] Of TGPPoint =
   ((x: 50  ; y: 50 ),
    (x: 100 ; y: 50 ),
    (x: 150 ; y: 100 ),
    (x: 100 ; y: 150 ),
    (x: 150 ; y: 200 ),
    (x: 100 ; y: 250 ),
    (x: 150 ; y: 300 ),
    (x: 100 ; y: 350 ),
    (x: 50  ; y: 350));
  Cnt = 45;
Var
  I: Integer;
  FGDIPlus: TGPGraphics;
  Pen: TGPPen;
  Path: TGPGraphicsPath;
  solidBrush: TGPSolidBrush;
  RMatr, TMatr: TGPMatrix;
Begin
  FBitmap.SetSize(Width, Height);
  FGDIPlus := TGPGraphics.Create(FBitmap.Canvas.Handle);
  //
  Pen := TGPPen.Create(TGPColor.Create(255, 0, 0, 0), 1 / FGDIPlus.GetDpiX);

  Path := TGPGraphicsPath.Create;
  Path.AddPolygon(PolyPoints);

  TMatr := TGPMatrix.Create;
  TMatr.Translate(Width / 2, Height / 2);
  TMatr.Scale(-0.5, -0.5);

  Path.Transform(TMatr);

  RMatr := TGPMatrix.Create;
  RMatr.RotateAt(360 / Cnt, TGPPointF.Create(Width / 2, Height / 2));

  For I := 0 To Cnt Do Begin
    solidBrush := TGPSolidBrush.Create(TGPColor.Create(255 - I * (255 Div Cnt), 255 - I * (255 Div Cnt),  I * (255 Div Cnt), 0));
    FGDIPlus.FillPath(SolidBrush, Path);
    FGDIPlus.DrawPath(Pen, Path);
    solidBrush.Free;
   // Rgn.Transform(RMatr);
    Path.Transform(RMatr);
  End;

  RMatr.Free;
  TMatr.Free;
  Path.Free;
  Pen.Free;
End;
```

Comment: А что значит - "работа с регионами абсолютно аналогична"? Преобразуются координаты самих регионов или трансформируется всё, что нарисовано внутри их?

Comment: @MBo, первое точно работает. Второе, может тоже возможно, но пока не знаю как